# Is there a limit to the number of Power Armor sets you can keep?

Tags: fallout-4

I've seen videos of some folks having several armor sets (4 is the most I've seen so far) standing about on their settlement. I'm wondering if having too many would cause some sets to disappear. They're not like guns/items that you can safely store in settlement crates, the suits kind of just... stand around.
(I know there's the extra step of taking out the fusion cores, so that NPC's don't use them.)

Is there a limit to the number of Power Armor sets you can keep?

Comment: As answers keep updating, you might want to consider updating the accepted answer. 10 no longer appears to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on 10 at the moment.

I'm not sure if they respawn, but there doesn't seem to be a limit on how many you can keep. If they don't respawn then it's simply how many you can get your hands on.

Comment: Wow, 10, that's great! I'll be working my way up then :)

Comment: They despawn after a while outside of settlements. Inside, they're fine.

Answer (score 5):

I am at 28, you just keep stealing them from BOS.

Pick pocket there power core, and they climb out and leave the suit.

Just wait for them to walk away put the core back in and free suit.

Comment: Even if you're friendly with the Brotherhood of Steel, you can get into the same ballpark. Between frames acquired from raiders, loot, and merchants, I'm at 27.

Comment: I don't have pickpocket, but I have a Rapid Pipe Pistol to shoot out their Fusion Core.  Same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm up to 25, so I'm thinking there's either no limit, or it's a pretty big number

Answer (score 1):

Unlimited if you keep finding them. Just store them in areas you trust. I have four. 3 in the red rocket and 1 on the pwrden

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I'm currently at 14 sets, I've heard of sets (that you find in the Commonwealth) respawning after about 4 in-game months but I'm not sure that's true. Though your sets won't disappear, just don't leave your fusion cores in any suits that are unused because settlers or provisioners can get into a suit and use it whenever they are fighting an enemy so just be sure to take the fusion cores out when you're done using them and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I got around 35 suits, but whenever I enter the settlement it becomes laggy.

You can get above the max item bar by maxing it out, dropping guns from your inventory and then picking them up in the settlement menu (don't scrap but just store them).

That way, the meter will decrease, but 35 is around the max for a single settlement.

So.. if you have all the settlements including the prdwn which is a safe zone)...

30*35 =1050~ suits you can have at maximum.
About the size of your own private army

Comment: What does the bar have to do with power armor suits?  They're not related...